# Can SPSS access data from SAS server through the SAS ODBC driver?

Tags: sas, odbc, spss

SAS-datasets in a SAS/SHARE server can be made accessible for ODBC-compliant applications using the SAS ODBC Driver (http://support.sas.com/downloads/browse.htm?fil=&cat=40)

I want to access such a server through ODBC from SPSS - is this at all possible?

Comment: what did you try? I mean where is your effort?

Comment: Just to clarify: you have a SAS/SHARE server set up which does work with other applications (excel, SQL server, whatever) and want to know if SPSS can also hit that?  Do you know how to connect to an ODBC connection in general with SPSS?

Answer (score 0):

SPSS can use any standard ODBC driver.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely it can - have you used SPSS to connect to an ODBC data source before?

If not, you should be able to set up an ODBC connection using the ODBC Data Source Adminstrator (on Windows): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/admin/odbc-data-source-administrator?view=sql-server-2017

And for SAS/SHARE in particular: http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/odbcdref/64777/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n1huqo74tuh90wn1vooxwjrqilgb.htm